# “the only + noun + to do sth” vs. “the only + noun + doing sth”

Tags: expressions

I am a senior high school English teacher in China. Recently I have come across a really tricky question in test.

In some textbooks in China, there is a fixed structure “the only + noun + to do sth”.

E.g.

> The only way to do great job is to love what you do.
>
> Mr. William is the only foreign friend to be present at the meeting
>
> Resolution is not the only way to consider when buying portable projectors.

**I am just wondering whether this structure exists or not?**

Recently I came across another sentence in a text completion task.

> The question is ”In fact, this isn’t the only positive program _______(involve) the younger generation.”

My answer is “to involve”. However, the correct answer is “involving”.

And I have attached the whole text completion task to this thread. Which I have question is NO.63.

Comment: Yes, *involving* is not more correct than *to involve*. Also off are: "The only way to do [a] great job " and "Resolution is not the only [quality?] way to consider."

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but interesting nevertheless, is a recent insurance-company advertisement on American television that  includes the tag line, "Only pay for what you need." The correct (and better) way of wording that tag line is "Pay for only what you need."

Comment: _Which involves the younger generation_ would be possible too.

Comment: *In some textbooks in China, there is a fixed structure “the only + noun + to do sth”.* This is not a "fixed structure": "only" can be changed for other adjectives, and "to do something" *The quick way to break it is to hit it.* can be changed for "of doing something". *The quick way of breaking it is hitting it.*